# Continuity of Optimal Stopping Time as a Function of the Starting Point

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Consider the time-homogeneous optimal stopping problem
$$V(x) = \sup_{\tau} E(f(X_\tau^x))$$
where $X^x$ is a diffusion starting at the point $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Typically, optimal stopping problems have an associated optimal stopping time
$$\tau(x) \equiv \inf \{t \ge 0 : X^x_t \in S\}$$
where $S \equiv \{y: V(y) = f(y)\}$ under appropriate conditions on $f$ and $V$ (see, for example, Peskir and Shiryaev in Chapter 1). I would like to understand under what conditions (if any) is $\tau(x)$ continuous as a function of $x$. Any references/insight would be massively appreciated!

Comment: $\tau (x)$ is a random variable, so it's unclear in what sense $x \mapsto \tau(x)$ could be continuous. Did you mean a functional of it? Perhaps its expectation?

Comment: Continuous as in "almost surely, the mapping $x \mapsto \tau(x)$ is continuous". I found part of an answer in Remark 4.5 of this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.07491, in case you or anyone else is curious.